# Error accessing object value

Tags: javascript

I have write this code to access object value in loop but it won't let me access in loop I am getting console error but when I access each value individually I don't get any error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var keys;
    var obj = [{"id":"1","firstname":"Aftab","lastname":"Altaf"},{"id":"2","firstname":"Haris","lastname":"Jaliawala"},{"id":"3","firstname":"Muzammil","lastname":"Mumtaaz"}];

    for(key in obj)
    {
        keys = Object.keys(obj[key]);
    }

    console.log(obj[0].firstname);

    for(value in obj)
    {
        console.log(obj[value].keys[value]);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output I am getting in my console.
**OUTPUT**

Aftab 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Anyone please help?

Comment: `obj` is an array, doesn't matter if you call it `obj`, it's still an array, and arrays are iterated with regular for loops, and the iteration only stores the last iteratet keys in the variable `keys`, not all of them, so it's basically all just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inplace of

```
console.log(obj[value].keys[value]);
```

use

```
console.log(obj[value][keys[value]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to access a dinamic property of an object in javascript -

you have to use [] and not dot notation.

Thats why you have to use `console.log(obj[value][keys[value]]);`